# methods of objects within main

Tags: java, oop

Is it possible to instantiate an object in a method within a class and then use one of the methods of the instantiated objects within main? Can I fix the following code?

```
    public class Test {

    public void Testmethod()  {

        someclass a = new someclass();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        a.methodfromsomeclass(); 

    }

}
```

Comment: No.  There is no reference to `a` in the `main()` method, so it can't refer to it.  What is it that you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Lets say you have few methods and each one of them is instantiating `someclass a`. Which one of `a` should be used in that case?

Answer (score 3):

There are three problems you need to fix:

1)  You've declared `a` to be a *local* variable inside `Testmethod`.  This means it can be accessed only inside `Testmethod`.  If you want a variable that will live even after `Testmethod` is done executing, you should make it an instance variable of `Test`.  That means that an instance of `Test` will contain the variable, and instance methods of `Test`, other than `Testmethod` will be able to access it.

Declaring an instance variable looks something like this:

```
public class Test {
    private someclass a;  // please choose a better variable name
    //...... other code ..........//
}
```

2)  `main` won't be able to access the instance variable, because `main` is static.  You can't make `main` non-static, either; Java requires it to be static.  What you should do is write an *instance* method (called `doMainStuff`, for example, or some better name), and have your `main` create a new `Test` object, something like:

```
public void doMainStuff() {
     // something that calls Testmethod
     a.methodfromsomeclass(); // use a better name than "a"
     // other code
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     new Test().doMainStuff();
}
```

3) The way you've written it so far, a new `someclass` would never be constructed, since you never call `Testmethod`.  You'll need to make sure you call `Testmethod` before you try to use `a`.  (It doesn't automatically get called just because it appears in the code.  You have to write code that calls it.)

Also, please obey proper naming conventions: classes begin with an upper-case letter (`SomeClass`), methods begin with a lower-case letter (`testMethod`), and if a name has multiple words, the second and later words begin with upper-case letters.

Comment: please can you give an example of making it an instance variable. The Testmethod() is called from another class. If I change to an instance variable would I still be able to call it from another class?

Comment: I've edited my answer with an example.  The `Testmethod()` method belongs to an instance of `Test`, so you need a `Test` object to be able to call `Testmethod()`; you wouldn't be calling `a` anyway.  This is all really basic stuff, and I recommend you go through a tutorial such as [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html) since you seem to be having problems with some of the basics.